# "mysql" database restored from another server. Is there a way to "regenerate it"?

Tags: mysql

last week we were doing a big site migration, dumped around 1200 mysql db and restored them. But in the process, we restored the "mysql" database, and then we lose all the privileges and users that were already created on the new server.

Is there a way to regenerate the mysql database? I dont mind about loosing the users and privileges, but i dont want to bring the old users to this new server.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You could hardly give less details but I suspect you installed MySQL and then headed to the datadir directory and replaced it (`mysql` folder included) with the files from the older installation. Am I right? Is it too late to do a proper backup? There's no guarantee that a file dump, generated God knows why, is not corrupted.

Comment: If you have a real mysql dump, the safest way might be to reinstall your mysql server and import it. Do not overwrite the mysql folder if you move / copy your old database folder, because it migth break your install if  you change the mysql version.

Comment: I think your question is off-topic, because it's about database administration not about programming.

Comment: Import the backup of the `mysql` database first (this is the most important db with most important tables on your server) then query  `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` and you should be back again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to hear that you clobbered your data! Most experienced DBA's do a backup before they do imports like the one you did, because we've all made the mistake you describe at least once.

If you have restarted your MySQL Server since you overwrote the mysql database, then no, you're out of luck. You have overwritten the data and after a restart it is now the official set of users, passwords, and privileges used by that server.

In that case, your only chance is if you have another backup of your old data from before it was overwritten.

If you only overwrote the data, but did not issue FLUSH PRIVILEGES yet, and also if you have not restarted the MySQL Server, then the old grants are still in memory. You can recover them with a tool like [pt-show-grants](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-show-grants.html).

Note if you use MySQL 5.7, this temporarily broke pt-show-grants, so you need to use at least version 2.2.20 of Percona Toolkit for the fix (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-toolkit/+bug/1435370 for details).

Comment: Thanks Bill. This was a clean restore, I mean, the new server had no users databases when restored the dump file. I'll try installing a new mysql server and then restore all databases again (except of course, mysql one)